# Weird string behaviour in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, unicode-string

I was curious what was the reason behind it. I have a string like this `'a⁢a'`. I normally would assume that the string length should be around 2. Instead I run `SELECT LEN('a⁢a')` which returns 3 instead of 2.

What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

I needed a few minutes to figure it out.

Assuming that there is some kind of hidden char in it, I suspected something like a carriage return or linefeed to be in there. I've tried different things like printing and substring all the way down.

In fact I came up with the idea, that there mus be a sign between the first and the second `a`. This can be proven by the following code.

```
SELECT LEN('a⁢a'), SUBSTRING('a⁢a',2,1)
```

Result:

```
----------- ----
3           ?
```

The fact, that the sign can't be displayed (`?`) points me to the unicode. After using a unicode string, the result changes.

```
SELECT LEN(N'a⁢a'), SUBSTRING(N'a⁢a',2,1)
```

Result:

```
----------- ----
3           ⁢
```

The Symbol is still invisible. I tried to retrieve the correct unicode symbol using this command:

```
SELECT LEN(N'a⁢a'), UNICODE(SUBSTRING(N'a⁢a',2,1))
```

Which results into:

```
----------- -----------
3           8290
```

It turns out that it is the [invisible times](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2062/index.htm) character in unicode. Just wanted to let you know this, in case that someone else comes along with something like this.

Comment: interesting.... `SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(N'a⁢a',2,1))` says 63 - which is "?" if i'm not wrong

Comment: Yes it is `?`, but it is instead a `UNICODE` string. I just thought about the `?` in first case too. ;-)